# Error when exiting cobol runtime. what can i do to fix it

Tags: c++

```
*** glibc detected *** /acu/722/bin/runcblrpc: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x082d8368 ***
                          ======= Backtrace: =========
                  /lib/libc.so.6[0xb7e38fc4]
                  /lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x9c)0xb7e3a95c]
                  /acu/722/bin/runcblrpc[0x8241053]
                          ======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08273000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1079681    /acu/722/bin/runcblrpc
08273000-08274000 r--p 0022b000 08:02 1079681    /acu/722/bin/runcblrpc
08274000-0827c000 rw-p 0022c000 08:02 1079681    /acu/722/bin/runcblrpc
0827c000-0835d000 rw-p 0827c000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7c00000-b7c21000 rw-p b7c00000 00:00 0
b7c21000-b7d00000 ---p b7c21000 00:00 0
b7d89000-b7d95000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1594594    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d95000-b7d96000 r--p 0000b000 08:02 1594594    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d96000-b7d97000 rw-p 0000c000 08:02 1594594    /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d97000-b7dcc000 r--s 00000000 08:02 671266     /var/run/nscd/passwd
b7dcc000-b7dcd000 rw-p b7dcc000 00:00 0
b7dcd000-b7f0a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1594443    /lib/libc-2.8.so
b7f0a000-b7f0c000 r--p 0013d000 08:02 1594443    /lib/libc-2.8.so
b7f0c000-b7f0d000 rw-p 0013f000 08:02 1594443    /lib/libc-2.8.so
b7f0d000-b7f10000 rw-p b7f0d000 00:00 0
b7f10000-b7f22000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1594676    /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
b7f22000-b7f23000 r--p 00011000 08:02 1594676    /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
b7f23000-b7f24000 rw-p 00012000 08:02 1594676    /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
b7f24000-b7f48000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1594454    /lib/libm-2.8.so
b7f48000-b7f49000 r--p 00023000 08:02 1594454    /lib/libm-2.8.so
b7f49000-b7f4a000 rw-p 00024000 08:02 1594454    /lib/libm-2.8.so
b7f4a000-b7f4c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1594449    /lib/libdl-2.8.so
b7f4c000-b7f4d000 r--p 00001000 08:02 1594449    /lib/libdl-2.8.so
b7f4d000-b7f4e000 rw-p 00002000 08:02 1594449    /lib/libdl-2.8.so
b7f4e000-b7f4f000 rw-p b7f4e000 00:00 0
b7f64000-b7f7f000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1594773    /lib/ld-2.8.so
b7f7f000-b7f80000 r--p 0001a000 08:02 1594773    /lib/ld-2.8.so
b7f80000-b7f81000 rw-p 0001b000 08:02 1594773    /lib/ld-2.8.so
bfc6c000-bfc81000 rw-p bffeb000 00:00 0          [stack]
ffffe000-fffff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
 ./fg4: line 23:  3247 Aborted
  /acu/722/bin/runcblrpc FG4RUN FM4-010
 End of FlexGen
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like memory corruption in your program; try setting `MALLOC_CHECK_` environment variable to `1`, `2`, or `3`, before running your program. [`MALLOC_CHECK_`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) with those arguments will ask the standard `malloc(3)` to perform more checks on the heap corruption. (Maybe `2` or `3` would be more useful, since they `abort(3)` the program immediately.)

If the simple `MALLOC_CHECK_` doesn't track it down for you, you may need to use [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) to find your error. (Another option is to try a [debugging memory allocator](http://dmalloc.com/), but I've never used one.)